# Best way - if any to "thin out" overly salty kimchi - already in jar

Tags: salt, kimchi

I made  Kimchi and put it into glass jars, based on this recipe:  https://www.feastingathome.com/how-to-make-kimchi/

I made it in 2 batches:

- 1 batch I accidentally put double the salt, but gave it an extra rinse after 4 hours. I also forgot to put the daikon in it.
- 1 batch I had normal salt and rinsed after 8 hours

When mixing with the paste I tasted the first batch and found it a bit salty, however I put both batched into jars nonetheless.

I'm concerned of both batches being to salty and inedible, so I thought of the following plan:

- taste each jar after 1 week
- if too salty, mix in another daikon to "thin out" and distribute the salt over more material.

To make sure I don't spoil the batches I was going to

- use a fresh fork to taste each jar
- get mixing bowls and forks straight out of a freshly run dishwasher
- mix with freshly dishwashed cutlery only

Is this a good approach or is there a better way to check and fix overly salty Kimchi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your idea is pretty much exactly the method used in Korea to mellow out salty kimchi. Apparently it works via osmosis. [Link in Korean](https://youtu.be/hqq45AfXE8o)

Just make sure to spread out the daikon, and let it sit for a few days before checking so that it can get the job done. Also, don't salt it beforehand (although this is admittedly quite obvious).

Comment: Just to confirm that this worked perfectly